# Use command line options of PhantomJS programmatically in CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to use PhantomJS's command line options programmatically?

Perhaps even from CasperJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't make sense to change the value for most of the [commandline options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) programmatically. For example, why would changing the cookies file or the disk cache option be a good idea during script execution?

Others can be set in the [settings](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) such as the `loadImages` and `webSecurityEnabled` options.

A special case is the [`phantom.setProxy`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11829) function which was merged into the master branch, but as of 1.9.8 not yet released. You will have to wait for PhantomJS 2.x to use it (or compile the source right now).

Comment: Thanks. I should have asked more specifically: Im looking for the option "--ssl-protocol", which is not included in the settings object. Do you know a way to access this from code? I tried setting webSecurityEnabled to false but it did not help accessing the website.

Comment: @aydunno As I said, if it cannot be set in the settings, then no. Why would you want to set it programmatically? I don't see a reason for this.

Comment: I run a script on an online IDE for CasperJS (casperbox.com). Without the neccessary access to the CLI. I just wrote the creator that he need to take care of HTTPS requests. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Writing to the creator is the proper action. You should have said in the question, what this is about.